# Synchronism and Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization

Well,

Imagine this:

```
synchronized (dataStorage) {
    dataStorage.add(hashMap);
    submitDataToServer();   
}
```

Also here, the method `submitDataToServer()`

```
private synchronized void submitDataToServer()
{
    if(dataStorage.size() > 0)
    {
        final HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = dataStorage.peek();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = new HttpWebRequest(context, ServicesName.getTravelServiceFullUrl(), false, hashMap) 
        {   
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) 
            {
                dataStorage.remove(hashMap);
                if(dataStorage.size() > 0)
                    submitDataToServer();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String result) 
            {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        submitDataToServer();
                    }
                }, tryAgainDelay);
            }
        };

        webRequest.execute();
    }
}
```

My question is about syncronization:

1) the calling to `submitDataToServer()` is under a synchronized block passing `dataStorage` object. When callback `onSuccess` is called, `dataStorage` still is under a synchronized scheme?

2) `onError` method starts an inner thread. Would `dataStorage` still be under a synchronized scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `webRequest.execute()` does not complete immediately, but rather blocks until it's time to call `onSuccess/onError`, then these methods will be called within the same `synchronized` block, but it will also defeat the entire purpose of having such a circuitous, callback-based API, whose primary purpose is to allow asynchrony.

Therefore, either your methods will not be called while holding a lock on `dataStorage`, or else they will but you are using the wrong kind of API to achieve that.

Comment: Any suggestion? My goal is "lock" `dataStorage` to avoid any write when a web request is on going.

Comment: Use a blocking API if you can, that would be the easiest way. Maybe there's a blocking "overlay" on top of the API you are using currently. If not, you can build one yourself. Just note that holding locks while wating on I/O with public internet is practically guaranteed trouble.